# Yii2 Swiftmailer - как передать параметр в layout письма?

Tags: yii2

Необходимо отправлять письма с разным текстом, но в одном общем `layout`. В `layout` в самом начале нужно писать приветствие пользователю, на подобии `Hello $user_name`, что бы в каждом письме отображалось это приветствие.

Как в `yii2` в `swiftmailer` при отправке письма можно передавать параметры именно в `layout`?

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы передать параметр в лейаут, нужно сделать следующее:

1. Передаем параметр:
   `\Yii::$app->mailer->getView()->params['userName'] = 'User Name';`
2. В самом лейауте выводим этот параметр: `params['userName'] ?>`
3. Очищаем переданные параметры:
   `\Yii::$app->mailer->getView()->params['userName'] = null;`

Подробнее о других нюансах работы со Swiftmailer можно почитать тут: http://atoumus.github.io/yii2-swiftmailer.html.